# C# animating a chess piece drag?

Tags: c#, drawing, draw, gdi+

I'm using a transparent picture box placed on top of a user control -("for which I'm using a chessboard image as a background")- to draw pieces and their movements using this code :

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selection)
        {
            Bitmap bgIMG= (Bitmap)Reference.Clone();//reference image with the selected piece removed                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bgIMG))
            {
                //SelPtIMG is a bitmap of the selected piece ("110x110"px)
                g.DrawImage(SelPtIMG, new Rectangle(e.X - 55, e.Y - 55, SelPtIMG.Width, SelPtIMG.Height));
            }
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bgIMG;
        }
    }
```

this works alright but it's somewhat slow , the piece lags behind the mouse cursor considerably , is there anything that I can do to speed up my code or even a faster alternative ?

*PS: all the bitmaps are 32bppArgb formatted.

Comment: Yes, first off cache the images you are drawing, maybe a big List<Bitmap>.  Use the paint events of the picturebox(I'd use a panel).  Set doublebuffer=true on the form.

Comment: @Trey The animation trajectory depends on the mouse movements , so I can't cache most of the Images , I also tried  with a panel but it didn't work at all.